# Tilemap collides with player and moves as one solid object (Phaser 3)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tile

I have a tilemap that I'm generating from an array, (I can't use tiled, the game will be procedurally generated) that I need to collide with the player, but instead of the player colliding with the wall layer, when the player goes outside of the camera bounds and the tilemap and comes back in, they push the tilemap off the screen. My tilemap code is here, simplified. I'm guessing I need to be able to add blank tiles, but I'm not sure how.

```
var room = [
  [1, 2, 2, 3],

  [4, 0, 0, 8],

  [4, 0, 0, 8],

  [5, 6, 6, 7],];

this.map = this.make.tilemap({ data: room, tileWidth: 64, tileHeight: 64 });
var tiles = this.map.addTilesetImage("wall");
var layer = this.map.createLayer('wallLayer', tiles, 0, 0)
layer.setCollisionBetween(1, 8, true, true, layer)
this.physics.add.existing(layer)
this.physics.add.collider(layer, this.player)
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: That should not happen, do you have some camera code, that you are using, like `startFollow` or so? Or could you share some more code, I can't reproduce this issue. I don't think the `map`, `layer` code is responsible for this issue.

Comment: https://glistening-checkered-mice.glitch.me/ is the page, https://glitch.com/edit/#!/glistening-checkered-mice?path=scripts%2Fgeneration%2Frooms%2Froom.js%3A302%3A157 is the project. All the tilemap code is in scripts/generation/camp.js, and all the setup for the player is in scripts/generation/room.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are adding the `layer` to the `physics` world with the line of code

```
this.physics.add.existing(layer);
```

> in the file `camp.js` ***line 126***

**This is not needed!** Since the two lines of code,

```
layer.setCollisionBetween(1, 16, true, false, layer); //(line 125) 
this.physics.add.collider(layer, this.player); //(line 127)
```

> in the file `camp.js`

set the collisions up between `player` and `layer`. No other action is needed to achieve collisions.

Comment: I changed it like you said to, it still has the same problem. EDIT: no it doesn't, i didn't reload the site. Thanks!

Comment: I also find it pretty interesting why it worked, correct me if i'm wrong, it was because when the layer was added as a pyhysics object, then it collided and moved as one whole. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Exactly, you are right. well I assume any object, that is added to the physics, and has dimesions, will be move by the physics engine, but I can't say for sure.